Is there a way to do a countifs when looking for specific parts of a variable string?
Example of what I'm looking for

Looking to see if this is possible -
I have 2 columns in an excel sheet and want to flag them for review if the description doesn't contain at least 2 words of the name in it (picture attached for clarification). Is this possible with a COUNTIFS? I've never used a COUNTIFS to identify just parts of a string before so not sure if it's possible.
I've never used a COUNTIFS to identify just parts of a string before so not sure if it's possible.

That is where wild-cards are useful. So yes, it is possible. Edit your question to show what you have tried, and where you have run into problems.

are you expecting the reason/explanation or is a simple "review" or "No review" good enough?

@sous2817 a simple review/no review is good enough! I haven't started the project yet, but haven't used a countif in this way so I wasn't sure if it was possible at all

I am not sure whether or not, you are looking for something like this, came up with two ways, one is bit complicated but other is simple one, think so:


• Formula used in cell D2
=IF(COUNTIF(B2:B5,"*"&SUBSTITUTE(A2:A5," ","*")&"*"),"No","Yes")


• Or, Formula used in cell C2
=LET(
     α, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(" "&A2:A5," ",{1,2})," "),
     IF(MMULT(COUNTIF(B2:B5,"*"&α&"*"),{1;1})<2,"Yes","No"))


